# Module Federation Angular Multi-Repo Accessing the API urls in Config.json

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

if someone can Help me with this Problem.
I am using Module Federation to build Angular Apps.
I have 2 Angular Apps, the ShellApp(Host) and the mfeApp(Remote).
the Remoteapp:
Load the Config.json in ConfigLoaderService :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppConfig } from '../Entities/app-config';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigLoaderService {

  basePath = '';
  isInitialized = false;
  signalrPath = '';
  userPath = '';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  initialize() {
    if(this.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }

    return this.httpClient.get<AppConfig>('./assets/config.json')
    .pipe(tap((response: AppConfig) => {
      this.basePath = response.basePath;
      this.signalrPath = response.signalrPath;
      this.userPath = response.userPath;
      this.isInitialized = true;
    })).toPromise();
  }

  public readConfig(): string {
    return this.basePath;
  }
  public readUserPath(): string{
    return this.userPath;
  }
}
```

and in the AppModule  I Provide the API Path (BASE_PATH) with the Value from the Config.json that the ConfigLoaderService => getBasePath return.
the ConfigLoaderServie initialize function is done in the PreloadFactory function in the APP_INITIALIZER:
and this is the Code :

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ApiModule, BASE_PATH } from 'testapi';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

// import { ConfigLoaderService } from './services/config-loader.service';
import { PreloadFactory } from './services/preload-service.factory';

import { TokenInterceptor } from './auth/helpers/token.interceptor';

import { ConfigLoaderService } from './services/config-loader.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
export function getBasePath(configLoaderService: ConfigLoaderService) {
  return configLoaderService.readConfig();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ApiModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ConfigLoaderService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      deps: [
        ConfigLoaderService
      ],
      multi: true,
      useFactory: PreloadFactory
    },
      { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-DE' },
    {
      provide: BASE_PATH,
      deps: [ConfigLoaderService],
      useFactory: getBasePath
    },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

when the Remoteapp start from its own, everything work fine the API Path (BASE_PATH) is Provided and the data come from the API.
BUT when I call the remteapp from the ShellAPP, the (BASE_PATH) is not Provided and

what is the best way that I can get and Provid the (BASE_PATH) from config.json File when I call the Remote App from the ShellApp?

I have try to load the Config.json from the featureModule (esgModule) but it still not work, I think it is Varaible scooping.
**EsgModule : **

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { EsgComponent } from "./esg.component";
import { MaterialModule } from "../material.module";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { EsgRoutingModule } from "./esg-routing.module";
import { APP_INITIALIZER, AfterViewInit, Inject, NgModule, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as fromPai from '../store/pai.reducer';
import { ConfigLoaderService } from "../services/config-loader.service";
import { BASE_PATH } from "testapi";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
export function getBasePath(configLoaderService: ConfigLoaderService) {
  configLoaderService.initialize();
  return configLoaderService.basePath;
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EsgComponent,
    TableComponent,
    TypeofPipe,
    CheckAndTransformPipe,
    SummaryComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}, {}),
    StoreModule.forFeature(fromPai.paiFeatureKey, fromPai.reducer),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    EsgRoutingModule
  ],
  providers:[ConfigLoaderService, { provide:BASE_PATH,deps: [ConfigLoaderService] ,useFactory:getBasePath}]
})
export class EsgModule   {
  customValue
  constructor(@Inject(BASE_PATH) private tokenValue: string) {
    this.customValue = tokenValue;
    console.log("test "+ this.tokenValue);
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js :**

```
const { withModuleFederationPlugin, shareAll } = require('./node_modules/@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({

  name: 'ISS.AM.WebClient.ESG.DATA',
  exposes: {
    './Module': './src/app/esg/esg.module.ts'
  },
  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },

});
```